# Excel lookup returning multiple values in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

Everyone -

I have seen numerous posts on this site similar to this, however with the way the data is laid out, none will work for what we are trying to accomplish.

I have a spreadsheet with columns having data B:DM.  Row 2 designates whether a value in A2 presents itself in one of the columns and using a conditional formula sets the appropriate color and response, i.e.  True = green, False = red.

[image: Sheet layout and data]

Below row 2 (row 3) is the column "header" describing the data the header represents.

What I would like to have is cell A3 to be a list of all column headers that match when row 2 = "True".  In other words, in the example image, `A4=Z_D_CA_5000_KEY_PROC_TEST_D, A5=Z_D_CO_5000_CO-LEAD_D`

Is this even possible?  I appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: 2013.  Sorry.  I know that xlookup offers some new interesting functionality but no such luck here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I haven't the time to write a formula with exact particulars here, but consider the following:

1. You say you have a formula controlling the Conditional Formatting ("CFG")
2. Said formula will work cell-side just as easily as in the CF feature
3. It must already be written with appropriate relative references or it couldn't properly control your CF
4. You can set up a formula in A3 that tests the row three range against that formula (`IF(B3:DM3=CF formula, B$2:DM$2&", ",""`)

and you have the basic idea. I have not tested that the formula needs {CSE} entry 'cause I'm not writing the actual formula you will write. But if it does, the do it, eh? Pretty sure you can have the formulas as standalones on each row, i.e.. no need for highlighting whatever, perhaps A3:A2003 and using {CSE}. Just do it for the row, then copy/fill down.

(People seem to do this a lot, know they have a formula in their CF, but completely forget they can put it into a cell too. Always remember, if there's a formula in CF, it works in cells too.)

Comment: Your response is much appreciated.

I think there is some confusion, which is not surprising as this is confusing me.  However, we are checking row 2 for TRUE or FALSE and then I am looking to return any and all column headers in row 3 that are TRUE.  So, I took your formula and changed it to (IF(B2:DM2=TRUE,B$3:DM$3&",","")).  However, now I am getting a #VALUE! error.  I guess I am not understanding how the formula is returning each of the column headers in row 3 if it finds TRUE in the row above it.  Thanks